# How to add ad in Linearlayout

Tags: android, admob

I was trying to add AdMob ads to my application.Ad display on bottom of screen but when it display my last few line hide by Ad.What I can do for automatically up current layout and display Ad. My code is

```
Window window1 = getWindow();
LinearLayout adsLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp2 = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
adsLayout.setGravity(Gravity.BOTTOM);
adView = new AdView(this, AdSize.BANNER, "xxxxxxxxxx");  
adsLayout.addView(adView);
AdRequest newAdReq = new AdRequest();
adView.loadAd(newAdReq);
window1.addContentView(adsLayout,lp2);
```

my xml file

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".ScienceActivity"
    android:id="@+id/addlayout"
     >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:text="@string/science" />
<View
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:background="#000000"
    android:paddingTop="20dp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/textbox"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:gravity="top"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
        android:lines="10"
        android:singleLine="false"
        android:editable="false"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:text="@string/Sciencearticle" />
    <View
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:background="#000000"
      android:paddingTop="20dp"
  />

    <Button 
        android:id="@+id/article"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:typeface="serif"
        android:background="#55ee00"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:onClick="articleClicked"
        android:text="@string/article"
        />

     <Button 
        android:id="@+id/times_article"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
         android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:typeface="serif"
        android:background="#55ee00"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:onClick="timesArticleClicked"
        android:text="@string/times_article"/>
      <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/addlayout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"        
        android:weightSum="1" >


        </LinearLayout>





</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: You can use relative layout for this purpose and position your layouts respectively.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do as follow

**XML**

```
<LinearLyaout MAIN 
     Height:fillparent
     Height:fillparent >

     <your main content area
        Height:fillparent
        Height:fillparent 
        weight:1>
     </your main content area>
     <Linearlayout 
          id:+@llAdd
          width:fillparent
          Height:wrapcontent/>
</LinearLayout>
```

**JAVA**

```
LinearLayout adsLayout = (LinearLayout)findviewbyid(R.id.llAdd);
adView = new AdView(this, AdSize.BANNER, "xxxxxxxxxx");  
adsLayout.addView(adView);
AdRequest newAdReq = new AdRequest();
adView.loadAd(newAdReq);
```

**EDITED XML**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
    android:id="@+id/addlayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".ScienceActivity" >

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/addlayout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="science"
            android:textSize="25sp" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:background="#000000"
            android:paddingTop="20dp" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/textbox"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:clickable="false"
            android:editable="false"
            android:ems="10"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:gravity="top"
            android:inputType="textMultiLine"
            android:lines="10"
            android:singleLine="false"
            android:text="Sciencearticle" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:background="#000000"
            android:paddingTop="20dp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/article"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:background="#55ee00"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:onClick="articleClicked"
            android:text="article"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="25sp"
            android:typeface="serif" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/times_article"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:background="#55ee00"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:onClick="timesArticleClicked"
            android:text="times_article"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="25sp"
            android:typeface="serif" />
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/addlayout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:weightSum="1" >
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: i try this code but it give error **"Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #74: Error inflating class Linearlayout"**

Comment: please post your layout xml file with your question

Comment: check this edited XML in my answer you just have to replace this xml with your and change the static text to String reference as per your need

Answer (score 0):

May this will helps  you:

```
LinearLayout adContainer = <container>;
AdView adView = new AdView(activity, com.google.ads.AdSize.BANNER, <publisher_id>);

// Initiate a generic request to load it with an ad
AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest();
adRequest.addTestDevice(AdRequest.TEST_EMULATOR);
adView.loadAd(adRequest);

// Place the ad view.
LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
adContainer.addView(adView, params);
```